# xcode UIScrollview not scrolling smoothly

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiscrollview

I would like to display a series of thumbnails where you can see a part of the next one, similar to how the app store works.

My issue is that scrolling to the next image is not smooth. If you swipe to the left too slow it bounces back to the same page but if you scroll too fast it scrolls too far then bounces back to the next slide. How can I make this smooth similar to the app store. I thought the function scrollViewDidScroll might do the trick but can't get it to work so heres my code so far:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

   int page = scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width;

   pageControl.currentPage = page;
   CGRect frame = scroller.frame;

   if (page == 0) {
     frame.origin.x = 0
   }
    else if (page == 1) {
     frame.origin.x = 195;
   }   

   else if (page == 2) {
     frame.origin.x = 410;
   } 

   else if (page == 3) {
     frame.origin.x = 630;
   } 

   frame.origin.y = 0;

    [scroller scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:Yes];

}
- (void)viewDidLoad
 {
   [super viewDidLoad];
    for (int i=1; i < 5; i++) {
     if (i == 1) {
       imagen.frame = CGRectMake(30, 0, 217, 317);
     }
     else {
       imagen.frame = CGRectMake((i-1)*217 + 30, 0, 217, 317);
     }

     [scroller addSubView:imagen];

    }

  scroller.delegate = self;
  scroller.contentSize = CSizeMake(320*4, 317);
  scroller.pagingEnabled = YES;

  pageControl.numberOfPages=4;
  pagecontrol.currentPage=0;
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

Where did allocated the scroll?

Just set paging enable to false.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to get this to work by turning off paging and some help from the following post: http://www.inediblesoftware.com/blog/2009/04/05/uiscrollview-paging-hack/